# Send value from cshtml (ASP.NET MVC) to js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass this to js module

home.cshtml

```html
<p id="timer" end-date="2030.12.31."
```

Presently sadly the cshtml file does not notice that the end-date is a variable.
I tried to set up there as
@{var end-date = .....}

But it did not really want to work out.

How can I send the date value to the js. And how do I code in the js file this.

thanks a lot

Comment: How is this related to ReactJS?  Is your actual `<p>` element closed and complete, or is it left open like this one?  How have you tried to read this custom attribute in JavaScript code?

Comment: <p id="timer" end-date="2030.12.31."></p>   Yeah that is closed....   Because the build is in asp.net but the static is in Reactjs

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to use custom attributes to store values is to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).  Any such attributes are automatically included in the `dataset` property on that element in the DOM.  For example:

```js
const timer = document.querySelector('#timer');
const endDate = timer.dataset.endDate;
console.log(endDate);
```

```html
<p id="timer" data-end-date="2030.12.31."></p>
```